# Should/How would I ensemble XGB models trained on the same data but with different parameters?

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost, ensemble-learning

Should I ensemble XGB models trained on the same data but with different parameters? I have N XGBRegressor models trained on the same data, but each has different parameters, for example:

```
Model 1:
Mean validation score: 0.497 (std: 0.433)
Parameters: {'alpha': 7, 'colsample': 0.263807428519774, 'eta': 0.3060158986459771, 'lambda': 9, 'max_depth': 3, 'min_child_weight': 8, 'subsample': 0.9574396763321433}

Model 2:
Mean validation score: 0.496 (std: 0.409)
Parameters: {'alpha': 10, 'colsample': 0.46293171278876444, 'eta': 0.060401759236472174, 'lambda': 1, 'max_depth': 5, 'min_child_weight': 7, 'subsample': 0.9262228216285202}

Model 3:
Mean validation score: 0.495 (std: 0.406)
Parameters: {'alpha': 1, 'colsample': 0.9232002538248327, 'eta': 0.6040805280556929, 'lambda': 5, 'max_depth': 4, 'min_child_weight': 11, 'subsample': 0.9419219597299463}
```

If so, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: I think you are talking about hyper-parameters tuning, please check the following link: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html

Comment: @ImSo3K No I've gotten the parameters for these 3 models using hyperparameter optimization, I'm asking if I can combine these 3 models.

Comment: What do you mean by combine? stack them to run one after another? take the best weights from each model and combine them to one?

Comment: I suppose I mean stacking them, not sure what is meant by taking the best weights, unless you are referring to feature importance.

Comment: Have you tried ensemble.StackingClassifier?  https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.StackingClassifier.html

Comment: Thank you, this seems like what I want to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

credit to @ImSo3k

```
sklearn.ensemble.StackingRegressor(estimators, final_estimator=None, *, cv=None, n_jobs=None, passthrough=False, verbose=0)
```

estimators will be a list of your regressors